# Completar registros faltantes en una consulta de selección SQL

Tags: sql

Se tiene una tabla donde falta información y la misma no se puede grabar en aquella.
La idea es realizar una consulta de selección, con dicha información, en SQL y completarla en cada mes faltante con la data que se encuentre en el primer mes siguiente. En la imagen adjunta intenté recrear la idea (en naranja, en el segundo cuadro, se asienta los registros a completar).
En el caso de llegar al ultimo registro, de ser necesario, completar con la información de dicho último registro hasta llegar al mes en curso. 
Lamentablemente no sé mucho de SQL y disculpen si falta algo de información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Son muchos registros? tiene que ser en sql? hay que escribir un procedimiento para esto.. dudo que puedas hacerlo con una instruccion SQL. Probaste algo?

Comment: En principio son alrededor de mil registros, pero con el paso del tiempo se suman mas. En realidad yo utilizo Power BI, y tengo acceso a SAP Hana Studio pero solo para traer unas vistas. Como cuando conecto la vista a Power BI hay un lugar para ingresar una sentencia de SQL (para reducir filas y columnas de las vistas), pensé que tal vez sería mas ágil crearlo ahí. Estuve probando con DAX pero no llego a buen puerto. Desde ya, Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Quien transforme los datos tiene que hacer un proceso justamente de transformacion y dejar la tabla ya lista para ser consumida. No podes andar arreglando la tabla todo el tiempo. Deberias ir arreglando a medida que llegan datos. Tu proceso de extraccion a tu dw debe hacerlo.

Comment: Hola, como estas?. Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta. SAP ya prepara esa tabla de esa manera. Sólo se completa cuando hay un cambio de valores dentro de un mes determinado (sino hay cambios, no hace nada). Probablemente haya otras tablas pero a las cuales no nos dan acceso y solo son vistas a las que podemos llegar (sin posibilidad ninguna de cambio). Entonces estimas que desde SQL no hay posibilidades?.

Comment: No puedo decir que no se pueda, porque no conozco tu arquitectura. Lo que estoy casi seguro es que no vas a poder solo con una instruccion SQL. Si con algun store procedure o algun otro tipo de proceso.